# redux-from validations in multiple tabs

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

[image]I have a requirement where I have to validate multiple forms(modal) which are in different tabs in a single component in react-js. Each tab has add icon when a user clicks on add icon it opens a modal window (which consist of form). I have to validate that form and submit it. Submit is working fine but here i got confused how to validate using redux-form here. Can anyone help which was the best way to validate the multiple forms? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

#### we can handle different submit and validations in redux-form here is an example

[redux-form Example](https://github.com/karenaprakash/redux-form.git)

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
/*------- connect redux with redux --------*/
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
/*------- action which all data to data base --------*/
import { addMessage } from './actions'
/*------- redux form --------*/
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
 
class Form extends Component {
 
   //PRISTINE / DIRTY // TOUCHED / ERROR : events in redux-form
 
/*------- renderInputField  --------*/
   renderInputField(field){
       const className = `form-input ${field.meta.touched && field.meta.error ? 'has-error':''}`;
       return (
           <div className={className}>
               <label>{field.myLabel}</label>
               <input type="text" {...field.input}/>
               <div className="error">
                   {field.meta.touched ? field.meta.error:''}
               </div>
           </div>
       )
   }
/*------- renderTextareaField  --------*/
   renderTextareaField(field){
       const className = `form-input ${field.meta.touched && field.meta.error ? 'has-error':''}`;
       return(
           <div className={className}>
               <label>{field.myLabel}</label>
               <textarea
                   {...field.input}
               ></textarea>
                <div className="error">
                   {field.meta.touched ? field.meta.error:''}
               </div>
           </div>
       )
   }
 
/*------- onSubmit() : runs on submit  --------*/
   onSubmit(values){
 
       this.props.addMessage(values,()=>{
 
       })
   }
 
 
   render(){
       return(
           <div className="Form">
               <div className="top">
                   <h3>Add a Message</h3>
                   <Link to="/">Back</Link>
               </div>
               <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit((event)=>this.onSubmit(event))}>
 
                   <Field
                       myLabel="Enter Title"
                       name="title"
                       component={this.renderInputField}
                   />
 
                   <Field
                       myLabel="Enter name"
                       name="from"
                       component={this.renderInputField}
                   />
 
                   <Field
                       myLabel="Enter message"
                       name="message"
                       component={this.renderTextareaField}
                   />
 
 
                   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 
               </form>
           </div>
       )
   }
}
/*------- validate() : validates our form  --------*/
 
 
function validate(values){
   const errors = {};
 
   if(!values.title){
       errors.title = "The title is empty"
   }
 
   if(!values.from){
       errors.from = "The from is empty"
   }
 
   if(!values.message){
       errors.message = "The error is empty"
   }
 
   return errors;
}
   /*------- it returns messages when action is called and state going to change  --------*/
 
function mapStateToProps(state){
   console.log(state)
   return {
       success: state.data
   }
}
 
   /*------- reduxForm : connects redux-form with react form   --------*/
 
export default reduxForm({
   validate,
   form:'PostMessage'
})(
   connect(mapStateToProps,{addMessage})(Form)
)
```